# Splitting one word document into multiple documents

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I have a 400 pages word document.

I want to split it into 80 documents with 5 pages from the original file.
1st - 5th page : Doc1
6th - 10th page : DOc2
..
396th - 400th page : Doc80

I am totally new to Macros. Can anybody give me the macro for the same

Comment: Since this ***is not*** a script/VBA/macro writing service, we are not here to do the work for you. This ***is*** a community of people helping each other when we run into problems trying to do something. What research have you done? Have you attempted anything yet? If so, share with us what and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called **Kutool for Word**, it has a lot of  options for document splitting.

Answer (score 0):

I use a variety of Linux utilities to manage document splitting and assembly on a regular basis.  You did not mention your workflow, but if you were to "print" the file to PDF, you could script pdfseparate or pdfjam to cut the document every 5 pages.  I then use utilities to re-assemble the documents with "standard" inserts.  It may be beyond the scope of your question, but it is an option for managing repeated tasks.